# mysql insert/update converts a number

Tags: mysql

I have two `mysql` columns both `int unsigned zerofill`. The first `5` in length, second `11` in length. First value takes any `5` digit number no problem. The second, no matter what converts any `11` digit number into `04294967295`. Any clue on what I can do to solve this puzzle?

Comment: That number is 2^32 - 1. That may be a clue.

Comment: int uses 4 bytes, so it stores the numbers: Signed: -2147483648 to 2147483647 and Unsigned: 0 to 4294967295

Comment: should I extend the column's length then or change to bigint?

Comment: yes.. you can specify it as bigint

Comment: in this case would it be better to have a char 11 or a bigint 11 in terms of 'weight' - is it a silly question?

Comment: it was a silly question I guess. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is larger than the integer field can handle - 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

Change the column to an unsigned BIGINT and you'll be good up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Comment: thanks, please advice: I can also store the value as char (11) would it be better than a bigint(11) in terms of 'space' taken?

Answer (score 0):

The length you give to an integer field is just for displaying. If you pass a length 11, a select commando on that column will display a number of 11 digits (which is the length of the number you got). The actual size of the field is determined by the type you chose for the column (`int`). `int`-fields are capable of storing 2<sup>32</sup> different values. For an unsigned field having 0 as its first value, this results in a maximum value of 2<sup>32</sup> - 1, which matches the number in your output. Since any 11 digit number you input will be bigger than this number, the value saved will be 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

You can overcome this limitation by using the `BIGINT`-type, which allows you to store any number up to 2<sup>64</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Range of UNSIGNED INT is 0 to 4294967295. so Any value above 4294967295, it will insert that max value, as that is the maximum value possible for unsigned INT.